# How to re-render a <t:selectManyCheckbox layout="spread">?

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, tomahawk

I try to re-render a `<t:selectManyCheckbox layout="spread">`. However, it does not re-render.

The Ajax call:

```
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{handler.property}">
        <f:ajax listener="#{handler.toggleItems}" render="items" />
    </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

The `t:selectManyCheckbox`:

```
<t:selectManyCheckbox id="items" layout="spread" forceId="true"
        forceIdIndex="false" value="#{handler.selectedItems}"
        required="true">
        ....
</t:selectManyCheckbox>
```

The listener is called and new values for the `<t:selectManyCheckbox>` are set, but it does not re-render.

Any ideas why? I tried `render="myForm:items"` and `render=":myForm:items"` too. It's in the same form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to re-render the spreaded `<t:checkbox>` items as well. I'd suggest to re-render the common parent of the `<t:selectManyCheckbox>` **and** all `<t:checkbox>` items. If not present, put them in a `<h:panelGroup>`.

E.g.

```
<h:panelGroup id="allCheckboxes">
    <t:selectManyCheckbox id="items" layout="spread" ... />
    ...
    <t:checkbox for="items" index="0" />
    ...
    <t:checkbox for="items" index="1" />
    ...
</h:panelGroup>
```

with

```
<f:ajax render="allCheckboxes" />
```

Comment: Works! (As usual!) Thank you!